# why after cleaning the 1 by 0 , its is returning 1 in Bit masking

Tags: c++, bitmap, bit-manipulation, bit, masking

See in this problem I want to clear the i_th bit which is 1 so after performing this method it should be 0 and should return 0, but its not  and should return 0 but its returning 1,
I don't know why, kindly explain this.

```
int clear_bit(int n, int i)
{
    int mask = ~(1 << i);
    return ((n & mask));
}
int main()
{
    int n = 5;
    int i = 2;
    cout << clear_bit(5, 2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you think `n` is in binary, given that you assign `n = 5`?

Comment: Your code is working correctly. Have you tried converting the numbers to binary on paper and doing the work by hand?

Comment: Are you sure you wanted to do bit manipulation on signed int? Usually it's being done on unsigned types. Not like it's UB, but it's rare.

Answer (score 2):

Integer `5` is bits `0000..00000101` in binary.

`1 << 2` is integer  `4`, which is bits `0000..00000100` in binary.

Inverting that value with `~` creates a mask containing bits `1111..11111011`.

Thus, AND'ing `n` with that mask, clearing bit 2, the result is bits `0000..00000001`, which is integer `1`.

```
  0000..00000101
& 1111..11111011
----------------
  0000..00000001
```

Had `n` been `4` instead of `5`, then the result would be `0` instead of `1`.

Answer (score 1):

`clear_bit` returns `1` because the result of evaluation is `1`

Let's walk through your example.

`n = 5` in binary is `101`

`clear_bit` does the following:

- Creates `mask` = `~(1 << i)`. `i = 2`, which means that this produces `~(0b100)`, which is `0b1111...1011`
- ANDs the `mask` with `n` (which as we established above, is `101`), resulting in:

  ```
    0b111...1011
  & 0b000...0101
  --------------
    0b000...0001
  ```

The only bits in common that are set are the 0th bit -- which evaluates the entire expression to simply `1`. Hence `1` being the result you are seeing.

Answer (score -3):

5 xor 2 = 5, so no bits will change value. That's expected

The standard library has code to manipulate bits, you might consider using that.

```
#include <bitset>
std::bitset<4> bits{"0101"}; // 5
bits.reset(2);
std::cout << bits.to_string() << std::endl; // output "0101"

bits.flip(2)
std::cout << bits_to_string() << std::endl; // output "0111"
```

Comment: It's not masking with `2`, it's clearing the 2nd bit (e.g. `1 << n`, which is `100` in binary). Did you read the question?